# angular dom sanitizer and svg byte array

Tags: angular, svg, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trying to bind a byte array to an image tag in angular.
I know the byte array is correct, because I can download it and view it from my API.

I created an image like this:

```
<img [src]="src" />
```

and then in my code, I sanitized the byte array like this:

```
this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`data:image/svg+xml,${this.location.qrCode}`);
```

in my console I can see this:

[image]

But the image isn't displaying. What am I doing wrong?

---

I have tried a few other things:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => (this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(e.target.result.toString()));
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([this.location.qrCode]));
```

and

```
this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`data:image/svg+xml;base64,${this.test}`);
```

and

```
this.src= btoa(this.location.qrCode);
```

and

```
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => (this.src = e.target.result);
    reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([this.location.qrCode]));
```

None of them worked :(

Comment: That looks like base64 encoding but the URL is missing the base64 keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and it turns out that my API base 64 encodes the byte array which is why it wasn't working.
I simply decoded it with this:

```
this.svgData = atob(this.location.qrCode);
```

and then was able to safely render the html:

```
this.svg = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.svgData);
```

Which I could use in my template like this:

```
<div [innerHtml]="svg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not encode it to base64 if the image is a svg with xml. Use base64 for images format like jpg.

Just add `data:image/svg+xml,` to the beggining of the image string.

In .ts:

```
constructor( 
    ...,
    public sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    ...
){...}

this.src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('data:image/svg+xml,' + this.location.qrCode);
```

In .html

```
<div [innerHtml]="src"></div>
```